# php корректное закрытие html тегов

Tags: php, битрикс

Нужен готовый скрипт (библиотека), что бы корректно закрывать html теги.

Например:

```
<div>
 <p><p>
</div>
```

должно закрываться не так:

```
    <div>
 <p><p>
</div></p></p>
```

Или наоборот, если есть закрытый тег а открытого нет, нужно поставить открывающий корректно.

Посоветуйте что нибудь пожалуйста.

Comment: Теги должны закрываться так же, как и скобки. Нельзя закрыть скобку так: `( [ { ] } )`.

Comment: То о чем вы пишете - это задача уровня ИИ. Может быть расскажите зачем это вам - вдруг вы пытаетесь микросокопом гвозди забивать.

Comment: Написал же, нужен скрипт. а не браузер, валидатор или текстовый редактор.

Я это делаю не за собой, есть 100к описаний товаров, где используется html. Не везде корректный html и из-за этого плывет верстка карточки товара.

Comment: @aat, смиритесь, такой библиотеки/скрипта нет. Если при закрытии тегов браузером едет верстка, то и при закрытии тегов библиотеками, которые используют те же движки, что и браузеры - так же все будет ехать.

Comment: **[1]** В Sublime Text 3 появился параметр  [auto_close_tags](http://www.sublimetext.ru/documentation/preferences/auto_close_tags), — очень помогает с закрытием тегов и обнаружением незакрытых.// **[2]** Пользуюсь плагином [HTMLPrettify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify), форматирующим разметку в удобочитаемую. Лишние или незакрытые теги становятся видны на поверхности.// **[3]** Ссылки на готовые страницы моего сайта прогоняю в зависимости от содержимого через [валидатор HTML](https://validator.w3.org/) или [валидатор CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

какую-то часть проблемы можно решить загрузкой в [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) и выгрузкой обратно. Он достаточно лояльно относится к таким ошибкам

Вот например такой код

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div>
 <p><p>
</div>');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

даст следующий результат:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>
 <p></p><p>
</p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Нечего, что входная разметка и так была валидной?

Comment: там два незакрытых параграфа - пример из вопроса

Comment: Два незакрытых параграфа - это валидная разметка.

Comment: в вопросе спрашивается, как закрыть незакрытый элемент. я написал вариант того, как. Про что ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Должно подойти [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.tidy.php)

> Tidy является интерфейсом к утилите очистки и восстановления Tidy
>   HTML, которая позволяет помимо очистки и восстановления также
>   манипулировать HTML-документами, а также перемещаться по дереву
>   документа.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы следить за вложенностью и закрытием тегов, используйте валидатор HTML кода и текстовый редактор для ручной коррекции тегов. Рекомендую валидатор по первой ссылке списка.

- W3C валидатор ([ссылка](http://validator.w3.org/))
- Для Firefox
  ([ссылка](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/))
- Для Chrome
  ([ссылка](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo))

Comment: валидаторы вроде просто проверяют а не расставляют

Comment: да. Использование валидатора и текстового редактора **с подсветкой синтаксиса** (например, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) существенно упрощает написание и редактирование HTML кода.

Comment: но не автоматизирует расставление парных тегов :)

Comment: @Grundy не только лишь все автоматизируют. Мало кто может это сделать.... Тем более так, как это хочет автор

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сам же сказал - браузеры отлично справляются :)

Comment: @Grundy они справляются с дополнением нехватающих. и то не всегда. но от этого шлака `<div>
 <p><p>
</div></p></p>` мало что спасет)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я бы сказал, что они справляются всегда, просто ожидаемый результат может оказать не тем что будет на самом деле :)

Comment: @Grundy не всегда))) а результат да - может огорчить....и я о том...... что это за браузеры или библиотеки должны быть, потомки Скайнета, который должны расставлять все теги так, как задумывает автор, даже если он их нашинковал через одного)) Это прям фатнтастика 2099 года

Comment: Судя по всему у автора вопроса есть задача делать эти проверки из своего кода. Веб валидаторы тут ни с какого бока.

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно правильно закрыть теги можно только вручную.

Можно в html-разметке каждый ваш блок класть в `<table><tr><td>`. Не очень красиво, зато внутри `table` не закрытые теги не сломают вам остальную вёрстку. Браузер нормально их понимает. Здесь на SO похоже сделано.

Хотя тут такой момент, что если в вашем тексте есть незакрытые теги `<table>`, то тогда есть вероятность что всё же вёрстка сломается.

Answer (score -2):

А как насчет библиотеки PhpQuery?

https://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/

Answer (score -2):

Выкосите все теги перед выводом описания названия и т.д. с помощью `strip_tags()` и не мучайтесь.